# How to get cpu and memory usage of nodes/pods in prometheus?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

As beginener, I have tried k9s and kubernetes '`kubectl top nodes`',for the cpu and memory usage and values are matched.Meanwhile I tried with prometheus UI, with '`avg(container_cpu_user_seconds_total{node="dev-node01"})`' and '`avg(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{node="dev-node01"})`'  for dev-node01. I cant get matching values.Any help will be appreciated as I am beginner.please any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`container_cpu_usage_seconds_total` is a [counter](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#counter), so you'll want to read up on what that means and how to query a counter.

In this case, you'll likely want to use the `rate` function, [documented here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#rate).

> `rate(v range-vector)` calculates the per-second average rate of increase of the time series in the range vector... `rate` should only be used with counters... Note that when combining `rate()` with an aggregation operator, always take a `rate()` first, then aggregate.

An example query for per-pod CPU usage would be:

```
sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{}[1h])) by (pod_name, namespace)
```

Also, you may want to check out [Kubecost](https://github.com/kubecost/cost-model) for k8s allocation metrics and APIs.

Comment: how to check for per node ? @Niko Kovacevic. I tried but could not match values with `kubectl top nodes`.

Comment: You can group by `node` instead of `pod_name, namespace`: `sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{}[1h])) by (node)` Also note that this is different than running `kubectl top nodes` in that it averages the usage over the given window. But it should be close.

Comment: yeah, I am getting close values. Did `avg` instead of `sum`. Meanwhile i tried with kubecost, looks interesting. Thanks for helping out.@Niko Kovacevic

Comment: Hi @AksahyAwate I am having the same issue, could you please give me your full working code that would matches closely with the `kubctl top nodes` command? And did you use any percentage?

Answer (score 2):

The following PromQL query returns CPU usage (as the number of used CPU cores) by pod in every namespace:

```
sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container!=""}[5m])) by (namespace, pod)
```

The `container!=""` filter is needed for filtering out cgroups hierarchy metrics - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69281327/why-container-memory-usage-is-doubled-in-cadvisor-metrics/69282328#69282328) for details.

The following query returns memory usage by pod in every namespace:

```
sum(container_memory_usage_bytes{container!=""}) by (namespace, pod)
```

The following query returns CPU usage (as the number of used CPU cores) by node:

```
sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container!=""}[5m])) by (node)
```

The following query returns memory usage by node:

```
sum(container_memory_usage_bytes{container!=""}) by (node)
```

Comment: `sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container!=""})) by (namespace, pod)` does not work because of the rate function.

Comment: Thanks, fixed queries with `rate()` functions above

Answer (score 0):

if metrics 'container_cpu_user_seconds_total' showing output then it should work. I used the same query which you mentioned above and it's working for me. Check the graph and console tab as well in Prometheus.

Please try this

```
avg(container_cpu_user_seconds_total{node="NODE_NAME"})
```

Comment: I am getting different values